# Filereader api image onload event for tiff image format not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I am using HTML5 file reader api to show the image preview before uploading the image to server but the problem is when i upload a tiff format image the on load image event is not triggering please see the code below

```
$('#file').on('change', function (e) {
    if (window.FileReader) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var image = new Image;
            image.src = e.target.result;

            image.onload = function () {
                alert();
            };
        };

 } else {
        alert('FileReader API is not supported in your browser, please use Firefox,        Safari, Chrome or IE10!')
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/qajexuwe/1

Comment: TIFs aren't a guarantee on the web. Therefore, you cant expect it to be loaded. In that case, the onload event will not fire - you'd need to catch onerror.